# Error al llamar programas de forma dinámica en Genexus Ev2 con Java

Tags: java, genexus

Tengo un procedimiento hecho en Genexus, que va llamando a otros de forma dinámica (comando `CALL(NombreDelPrograma)`, sacando el nombre de dichos procedimientos de la base de datos.
Todos los ejecuta bien, menos uno, que es el *informarrechazosdgi*, y no me doy cuenta por qué.

Tengo una tabla dónde grabo las excepciones, y me arroja la siguiente:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException Can't execute dynamic call informarrechazosdgi - org/bouncycastle/jce/spec/ECPublicKeySpec
    at com.genexus.db.DynamicExecute.dynamicExecute(Unknown Source)
    at procesarevento.privateExecute(procesarevento.java:639)
    at procesarevento.execute_int(procesarevento.java:45)
    at procesarevento.execute(procesarevento.java:32)
    at procesarevento.S11345(procesarevento.java:708)
    at procesarevento.privateExecute(procesarevento.java:341)
    at procesarevento.execute_int(procesarevento.java:45)
    at procesarevento.execute(procesarevento.java:32)
    at dispararevento.privateExecute(dispararevento.java:134)
    at dispararevento.execute_int(dispararevento.java:72)
    at dispararevento.execute(dispararevento.java:53)
    at tpactualizarsobres.privateExecute(tpactualizarsobres.java:47)
    at tpactualizarsobres.execute_int(tpactualizarsobres.java:38)
    at tpactualizarsobres.execute(tpactualizarsobres.java:30)
    at pruebasdeprocedimientos_impl.e152J2(pruebasdeprocedimientos_impl.java:501)
    at pruebasdeprocedimientos_impl.evt2J2(pruebasdeprocedimientos_impl.java:363)
    at pruebasdeprocedimientos_impl.dispatchEvents(pruebasdeprocedimientos_impl.java:214)
    at appmasterpage_impl.evt012(appmasterpage_impl.java:238)
    at appmasterpage_impl.ws012(appmasterpage_impl.java:142)
    at appmasterpage_impl.webExecute(appmasterpage_impl.java:54)
    at pruebasdeprocedimientos_impl.webExecute(pruebasdeprocedimientos_impl.java:92)
    at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebObjectBase.doExecute(Unknown Source)
    at pruebasdeprocedimientos.doExecute(pruebasdeprocedimientos.java:21)
    at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebObjectStub.callDoExecute(Unknown Source)
    at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebObjectStub.callExecute(Unknown Source)
    at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebObjectStub.doPost(Unknown Source)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.genexus.filters.ExpiresFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

La librería *bouncycastle* la tengo tanto en el *lib* de la webapp, como en la carpeta *lib* del tomcat.
Saben por dónde puede venir la mano ?

Es GX Ev2 generando Java.

Esto es una de las tantas excepciones que arroja el log del tomcat:

```
abr 19, 2016 6:38:42 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase loadClass
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JDKDSASigner$ecDSA.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1745)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1703)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.getImplClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.Signature.isSpi(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.Signature.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.JsseJce.getSignature(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.JsseJce.isEcAvailable(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite$KeyExchange.isAvailable(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite.isAvailable(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.getApplicableCipherSuiteList(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.getDefaultCipherSuiteList(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.init(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.ReflectionSocketFactory.createSocket(ReflectionSocketFactory.java:116)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SSLProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:130)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.open(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1361)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPSender.executeMethod(AbstractHTTPSender.java:621)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:193)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:75)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:404)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:231)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:406)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
    at uy.gub.dgi.WS_eFacturaStub.eFACCONSULTARESTADOENVIO(WS_eFacturaStub.java:500)
    at uy.gub.dgi.gx.DGIEfactura.executeEFACCONSULTARESTADOENVIO(DGIEfactura.java:271)
    at uy.gub.dgi.gx.DGIEfactura.ExecuteDGIWS(DGIEfactura.java:176)
    at uy.gub.dgi.gx.DGIEfactura.EFACCONSULTARESTADOENVIO(DGIEfactura.java:153)
    at uy.dgi.ws.DGIWSWrapper.EFACCONSULTARESTADOENVIO(DGIWSWrapper.java:66)
    at SdtDGIWSWrapper.efacconsultarestadoenvio(SdtDGIWSWrapper.java:71)
    at consultarsobreadgi.privateExecute(consultarsobreadgi.java:122)
    at consultarsobreadgi.execute_int(consultarsobreadgi.java:48)
    at consultarsobreadgi.execute(consultarsobreadgi.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.genexus.db.DynamicExecute.dynamicExecute(Unknown Source)
    at procesarevento.privateExecute(procesarevento.java:411)
    at procesarevento.execute_int(procesarevento.java:45)
    at procesarevento.execute(procesarevento.java:32)
    at procesarevento.S11345(procesarevento.java:709)
    at procesarevento.privateExecute(procesarevento.java:240)
    at procesarevento.execute_int(procesarevento.java:45)
    at procesarevento.execute(procesarevento.java:32)
    at dispararevento.privateExecute(dispararevento.java:134)
    at dispararevento.execute_int(dispararevento.java:72)
    at dispararevento.execute(dispararevento.java:53)
    at tpactualizarsobres.privateExecute(tpactualizarsobres.java:47)
    at tpactualizarsobres.execute_int(tpactualizarsobres.java:38)
    at tpactualizarsobres.execute(tpactualizarsobres.java:30)
    at pruebasdeprocedimientos_impl.e152J2(pruebasdeprocedimientos_impl.java:501)
    at pruebasdeprocedimientos_impl.evt2J2(pruebasdeprocedimientos_impl.java:363)
    at pruebasdeprocedimientos_impl.dispatchEvents(pruebasdeprocedimientos_impl.java:214)
    at appmasterpage_impl.evt012(appmasterpage_impl.java:238)
    at appmasterpage_impl.ws012(appmasterpage_impl.java:142)
    at appmasterpage_impl.webExecute(appmasterpage_impl.java:54)
    at pruebasdeprocedimientos_impl.webExecute(pruebasdeprocedimientos_impl.java:92)
    at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebObjectBase.doExecute(Unknown Source)
    at pruebasdeprocedimientos.doExecute(pruebasdeprocedimientos.java:21)
    at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebObjectStub.callDoExecute(Unknown Source)
    at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebObjectStub.callExecute(Unknown Source)
    at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebObjectStub.doPost(Unknown Source)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.genexus.filters.ExpiresFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: ¿Has comprobado que tienes las librerías de bouncycastle en el classpath de tu aplicación, que es la versión adecuada y que se están cargando correctamente al ejecutar la aplicación? Además, sería bueno que agregues el stacktrace completo.

Comment: Al menos agrega tu clase donde se encuentre el método : informarrechazosdgi

Comment: Parece evidente que no tienes acceso al proveedor de JCE, en este caso la librería *Bouncy Castle*. Puede estar ocurriendo que accedes a la librería en tiempo de compilación pero en tiempo de ejecución no. Verifica que el Tomcat tiene en su directorio *lib* la librería de *Bouncy Castle* o en el directorio *lib* del war de aplicación, en alguno de los dos sitios debe estar.

Comment: Tengo la librería en las 2 carpetas, tanto en la del tomcat como en la de la webapp.
La versión de tomcat es la 7.

Answer (score 1):

Logré solucionar el tema. El problema venía porque tenía duplicada la librería bouncycastle; estaba tanto en la carpeta *lib* del Tomcat como en la carpeta *lib* de la webapp.

Saqué la librería de la webapp, y funcionó todo bien.